# method overriding for member variable

Tags: variables, member, overriding

My understanding is that we can't override the member variable but when i am running the below program, i am getting unexpected o/p

```
    class Parent {
    String message = "parent";
    void say() {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
    }

    class Child extends Parent {
        String message = "child";
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Child().say();
    }
}
```

In the o/p i am getting "**parent**" While we are calling the say method using child object and even there is no Parent reference.

Can anybody help me to understand it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "say" method is on the parent class, not on the child. So when it call for the "message" member it looks at his own, not at the child's one. The fact that the call is make through a child class has nothing to do in it.
Indeed, the member variable is not overriden here. This is expected behavior.

EDIT :

The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html) says that "If the class declares a field with a certain name, then the declaration of that field is said to hide any and all accessible declarations of fields with the same name in superclasses, and superinterfaces of the class."

"Inherit" does not mean "copy". When you call the "say" method on a child instance, is not a "code copy" of the method that is called, but the method of the parent class, as it is defined in the parent class. And the parent class know nothing about the child variable member.

Comment: I agree that "say" method is in parent class but it is also inherited into the child class So shouldn't it print the child class member variable.

Answer (score 0):

*your child class is extend parent class features! so child class has say method by default and it's value (parent) because parent class say method will called when you call say method from child object. if you want to print "child" instead, you need override your say method in the child class and change that default feature, which extends from parent class.*